# stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString lowercase & capitalizedString Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

How can i solve the problem ?

```
NSString * vendorName=@"can't event";
vendorName= [[[vendorName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"]    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\\'"] capitalizedString];
```

Output i am receiving is **Can\'T Event**

But, i need result as **Can\'t Event**

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSString *vendorName=@"can't event";
vendorName= [[[vendorName capitalizedString] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"\\'"];
```